# What circuit capacity will I need for a strand of outdoor lights?

Tags: lighting

I'm running a strand of lights around my backyard. There's a total of 33 lights. These will only be used in the summer, and taken down in the fall.
What size plug end (amperage Wise), what size circuit, and will I need to change the normal outlet?

Comment: Can you give us more information on the strand of lights?

Comment: Are you in the USA or someplace else?  (Voltage and plug styles vary by country).  In the USA, 33 is a magic number for a string of *LED lights*, but “standard lights” in the title adds confusion if my guess is correct.

Comment: I'm in the US. By standard I simply meant standard E26 size bulb base, not anything else. We're not certain on if we will use Edison style bulbs or LED party bulbs.

Comment: How many watts / lumens will be needed ?

Comment: Find LED bulbs for this.  Regular plug.  350 is long, you want the least total watts possible.  Is this a loop that comes back, or is it a one way run?  If it comes back to the house consider cutting it in half and plugging in two instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of 33 bulbs in a string is based on each socket being limited to 40W (it will say that somewhere). 33 x 40 = 1320W, divided by the worst case scenario of 110V (nominal is now 120V, but many places still only provide 110V, so they have to cover that). So 1320W / 110V = 12A, which is the limit of what you can put on a 15A circuit breaker (80% load).

I agree that 350ft is a long distance for a load of 12A, but MOST people in the US will have closer to 120V, so if it drops to 110V, that's still covered. The problem may be if you only have 110V at the outlet, the voltage will drop even more. But on incandescent bulbs that just results in less light, not more current.

If you use LED bulbs however, where the equivalent light of 40W incandescent bulbs will only use 4.5W each, the current will go down significantly (less than 2A total) and there will likely be no perceivable voltage drop.

Answer (score 0):

350ft on 14ga wire is going to be some serious *voltage drop*. With that length, its not a "Let's just run some wire and bulbs and plug it in" thing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The voltage drop depends on the current draw; it sounds like these lights won't be drawing much current, so the drop shouldn't be too bad. (Plus, if it does, the lights will just get a bit dimmer.)

Comment: @DanielGriscom You want enough fault current to actually trip the breaker on a short, though. That doesn't depend on load, only on total impedance and the current required to trip the breaker.